# SQL Trigger to check if a value exist on another table after insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I've been trying to make a trigger work. My aim is to have a trigger check if a value exist on another table on insertion to a table.
Below is the trigger that is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON  table1
AFTER INSERT     
AS 
declare @tId int

IF EXISTS ((Select @tId from inserted i join table2 on i.tId=table2.Id 

join table3 on i.tId=table3.tId 

where i.tId NOT IN (SELECT tId from  table3) 

and table2.ApplicationDate > '2018-01-31 00:00:00.0000000' 

and table2.cnumber is NOT NULL))

BEGIN

    ROLLBACK transaction
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

END

GO
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working?

Comment: Silently rolling back may cause confusion in the future...

Comment: `Select @tId` is suspect and probably not what you want, that gives you `NULL` for all rows. Since you're using `EXISTS` it doesn't matter what you use here (`SELECT 0` would work as well) but it suggests you're not clear on the semantics of things. What's `@tId` supposed to be good for here, anyway?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this feels like this could be handled by proper use of foreign key constraints.

Comment: Ok @Murenik From the trigger, the subquery should have some values in it. Now, if tId from the inserted values exist in the subquery result, then the inserted row on the table should be rolled back. But, when the trigger is applied, the rows are not being rolled back. All rows get committed.

Comment: @stickybit It is not a silent rollback. There are some records that have been created on a table that are illegal. The trigger is to make sure that those rows cannot be updated.

Comment: @stickybit if feel like you should be handling this in the insert query.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu. This sounds like you should be using constraints instead of a trigger.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is unclear.
These parts in combination makes no sense:

```
join table3 on i.tId=table3.tId 
where i.tId NOT IN (SELECT tId from table3)
```

-> NO MATCHING ROWS!

The simple solution for checking both tables without dependency between it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
    ON table1 AFTER INSERT     
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM table2 WHERE Id IN(SELECT tId FROM Inserted))
        OR EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM table3 WHERE Id IN(SELECT tId FROM Inserted))) BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END
END
```

Comment: Thank you @7schmiede. But your solution did not do it as well. Rows in illegal table are still allowed to be inserted in the legal table.

Comment: Wich Table is legal and wich is illegal? Please describe your 3 tables and intentions a little closer, then I will revise the query.